# Объединение гипервизоров (общая консоль управления)

Tags: vmware, виртуализация, kvm, proxmox

коллеги!
Столкнулся с новой для меня задачей - требуется объединить два типа гипервизоров под одной консолью управления. Т.е. необходимо из одного интерфейса создавать, удалять, управлять ВМ и прочим функционалом виртуализации.
На данный момент виртуализация представлена vmware и proxmox.
Если кто-нибудь сталкивался, то подскажите с помощью какого решения лучше всего это сделать.
Одно из важнейших условий - чтобы решение было бесплатным.
Заранее благодарю за ответы.